# DevOps options for pipeline for a mobile app

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, devops, vps

I am looking to build a mobile app that will send 100 mb of data per instance to a "cloud" system where the data will be manipulated, machine learning models applied to it (not built upon), then the summarised data should be sent back to the users phone.  I have written much of my scripts on my local machine and now I need to begin to deploy it.  Both in terms of deploying in the cloud, and in app development, I have no experience.

I initially planned to run this all on GCP.  However loading models is a bit of a challenge.  Whilst working through this, someone suggested that perhaps what I need is a VPS.  Initial views suggest yes a VPS could host my data and do my processing for me and a significant cost reduction.  However, GCP has the benefit of having Firebase linked to it, and so there is then the question of how I could set up the VPS to receive the data and send it back out to the app.

I know that this is very generic and please ask me more questions so I can clarify as far as I can.  My challenge is how to get started in this whole area which I do not have experience in.  Links to relevant tutorials / courses which would help me on this path, would be of great help.

In terms of size and frequency of my set up:

1. One push of data is approximately 100mb.  The data sent back will be much less (currently undefined but its summary statistics)
2. This will then happen up to 5 times per week, and I would hope for 5000-10000 customers

Appreciate any help and hints you can give me, and if this is deemed inappropriate because its not specific enough, could you advise where I could seek the help I am after.
Thank you,
James

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) to create a VM for hosting your app.

To get started, you can create a GCP account which is provided with a credit and follow this [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) to see how it works.

As for the additional resources to help you become familiar with the platform, I can recommend [GCE tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials) and [Quicklabs](https://www.qwiklabs.com/focuses/11952?parent=catalog).